# What can I do for my robot mop cleaner to climb 2-3 cm elevated floor(step)?

Tags: home, cement

Recently, I brought a robot mop cleaner and is working fine.

The only issue I am facing is that there are elevated floors between rooms and the mop cannot able to go from room A to B if there is an elevated floor between them. It can go from B to A nicely. The length of elevation is 2-3 cms. Simply, it can go downwards but cant go upwards.

I don't want to fill the elevation with cement. I want some material that can able to fill diagonally so that my mop can climb it.

What can be an option for me in this context?

Comment: Would you consider wood? Consider my answer.

Comment: Set up a cleaning schedule: room 1 on Monday, room 2 on Tuesday, etc . Close the door to that room and let 'er rip, (figuratively speaking.)

Answer (score 2):

**Shim & Shine Floor Hack**

Have you ever heard of SHIMS? They are wedges - thin strips of building material thicker on one end than the other. Contractors use them to fill spaces between things to make them solid and stable. They are also called 'wobble stoppers'.

Visit a building supply or a lumber yard. There, for a few dollars you can buy a package of them made of cedar wood, although you can also find them made of plastic, too.

[image: SHIMS][image: cedar wood shims]

Here's the nice part. They are solid, light, and already the size you need - (~1.25 x ~20 cms.) I used them to smallify the height of the thick door sills between rooms in my apartment.

Your job is to place several beside each other to make a gradual slope for your robo-mop/vac to negotiate. You can use a second layer to increase the slope if necessary.
 When they are in place, use something (tape?) across them to hold them together in place - you won't need much.

I put a small 'throw' rug over mine so that the floor appears more finished; but, you can go OCR and finish the slope to match your home decor. That's it!

I think you'll be inclined to like this hack!

Good luck

Comment: I wasn't aware that automated cleaners had Optical Character Recognition (OCR) but I suspect you meant OCD. (grin)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of materials suitable for building a ramp. The height difference is one of two parameters necessary to determine a suitable material. The other parameter is often called the "run." In roofing terms, it's rise over run. For the purposes of this discussion, we'll consider that you have only reasonable limitations on the value for run and ignore it, more or less.

One must expect that the ramp will take force from a human being stepping on it, which eliminates a hollow design using, for example, cardboard.

Modeling clay which will harden over time may serve your requirements. A generic term is oven-bake clay. The material would be shaped to your location and heated per instructions. It may require reinforcement within the material, akin to rebar for concrete. This could be fine wire mesh, perhaps 6 mm / 0.25 inch spacing.

Another option is stacked flat solid material. Many options here, such as linoleum tile. The first layer encompasses the entire width and run, while the next layer is a few mm shorter in the run dimensions. Each subsequent layer is shorter by an appropriate amount until the top layer mates with the higher surface.

```
_
____
_______
___________
_________________
```

With a material such as linoleum tile, one can contour the edges to remove the abrupt transition, but it's likely your machine can handle the minimal jump of a suitably tapered stack.